I want to use first API response in another Query without call it second time
I am creating new session in below query which name is Create_Session.
let
    BaseURL = BaseURLPara,
    body = "{""sessionId"":null}",
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(BaseURL,
[
RelativePath = "/testAPI/session/create_session",
Content = Text.ToBinary(body),
        Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"]
    ])),
    newSessionID = Source[data][newSessionID]
in
    newSessionID

This created SessionId I want to pass in below new Query but when I refresh all then /testAPI/session/create_session call two times in backend.I do not want to call /testAPI/session/create_session in below query because I already pass Sessionid using variable (Createsession) then why /testAPI/session/create_session call in below Query?
let
    BaseURL=BaseURLPara,
    Createsession=Create_Session,
    body="{""sessionId"": """ & Createsession & """,
    ""isSearch"": false,
    ""keyword"": """",
    ""exploreType"": 2}",
    Source=Json.Document(Web.Contents(BaseURL,
[
RelativePath="/testAPI/explorer/location_hierarchy",
Content=Text.ToBinary(body),
                Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json"]
        ])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    Value = #"Converted to Table"{1}[Value],
    #"Converted to Table1" = Record.ToTable(Value),
    Value1 = #"Converted to Table1"{0}[Value],
    #"Parsed JSON" = Json.Document(Value1),
    #"Converted to Table2" = Record.ToTable(#"Parsed JSON"),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table2", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"EntID", "EntityName", "Name", "Description", "Type", "Icon", "Room"}, {"EntID", "EntityName", "Name.1", "Description", "Type", "Icon", "Room"}),
    #"Expanded Room" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "Room"),
    #"Expanded Room1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Room", "Room", {"EntID", "EntityName", "Name", "Description", "Type", "Icon", "Floor"}, {"EntID.1", "EntityName.1", "Name.2", "Description.1", "Type.1", "Icon.1", "Floor"}),
    #"Expanded Floor" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Room1", "Floor"),
    #"Expanded Floor1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Floor", "Floor", {"EntID", "EntityName", "Name", "Description", "Type", "Icon", "HasChildren"}, {"EntID.2", "EntityName.2", "Name.3", "Description.2", "Type.2", "Icon.2", "HasChildren"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Floor1",{{"EntID", "Parent ID"}, {"Name.1", "Site Name"}, {"Type", "Room Type"}, {"Name.2", "Room Name"}, {"Name.3", "Floor Name"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"Description", "Icon", "Description.1", "Icon.1", "Description.2", "Icon.2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

